# 24hour clock substraction python

Tags: python

Probably a billy basic question, I can insert the current hour into my python but I want to be able to subtract 3 hours from it. I've tried the below but this just prints out the hour - 3.

I need the time to be in 24 hour format because I need to keep the leading zero. Where am I going wrong?

```
import time
print (time.strftime("%H -3"))
15 -3
```

Comment: Can you use datetime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to subtract the hours **before** formatting the time.

This is much easier using the [`datetime` package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> then = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
>>> then.hour
16
>>> then.strftime('%H')
'16'
```

but you can do it with the `time` module too, provided you subtract seconds:

```
>>> import time
>>> now = time.mktime(time.localtime())
>>> then = now - (3600 * 3)
>>> time.localtime(then).tm_hour
16
>>> time.strftime('%H', time.localtime(then))
'16'
```

Comment: To add further complication. I require two '%H' hour times in my script. One will be the current hour and the other with be 3 hours less. Using python to make a SOUP request with a start and end time parameter!

Comment: import datetime;
now = datetime.datetime.now()
then = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
print then.strftime('%H')
print time.strftime('%H')

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().hour
(datetime.datetime.now()  - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)).hour
```

Comment: And now subtract 3 hours at 1 am in the morning.

Comment: `(datetime.datetime.now().hour - 3)%24` is maybe what he meant ? ... but I think the right way to do it is the timedelta

Comment: (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)).hour